# Pyspark dataframe data type for all columns changed to String by UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have  a dataframe which have few columns like email_address(String), paid(integer) and date(datetime type)

I'm running a UDF as mentioned below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def conv(column):
    date_format='%m/%d/%Y'
    a = None
    if column:
        try:
            a= datetime.strptime(str(column),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime(date_format)
            print("Inside Try")
        except:
            a = column
            print("Inside except")
    return a

conv_func = udf(conv)

df_new = date_df.select(*(conv_func(col(c)).alias(c) for c in date_df.columns))
```

So in df_new I'm expecting email_address(**String**), paid(**integer**) and date(**string**) with changed format from YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY .

The problem is UDF does converts the format but also changes the datatype of **paid column to string from integer** which I didn't anticipated for.

I wonder how to avoid that using this UDF.

Comment: Why the `from pyspark.sql.types import StringType` and where is your `udf` type? E.g. `udf(conv, StringType())`

Comment: Since I don't want the type to be Strictly StringType I didn't mentioned the udf type. As you would have noticed dataframe has integer type too and I don't want to cast that column to String.

Comment: I have removed the unused imports.

Comment: The udf must have a type unfortunately and by default, if you do not specify it, it will be "StringType" [src](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration)

Comment: Any Idea how could I retain the types of other column utilizing the same UDF?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Why would you apply date formatting to an email. Just use `withColumn` on the column you actually want to transform. And don't use `udf`. SQL functions can easily do it.

Comment: This is just a sample I actually have a big dataframe with 1000+ attributes and there are around 150 date related columns. Instead of selecting only date columns and applying the UDF on the same and then joining with the original dataframe I want to pass the entire dataframe, and as the Try block suggests if it receives any other column apart from datetime object it will pass it on as it is and only modify the datetime related columns. Issue is I need to specify a UDF type which is uniform to all columns. I just want to understand if there is a way I can have any data type returned from a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this in the way you are trying.

Use a function to test if a column is a date and only apply your conversion on those.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

def conv(column):
    date_format='%m/%d/%Y'
    a = datetime.strptime(str(column),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime(date_format)
    return a

def is_date(column):
    try:
        conv(column)
        return True
    except:
        return False

conv_func = udf(conv)
date_udf = udf(is_date, BooleanType())

df_new = date_df.select(
    *(conv_func(col(c)).alias(c) if date_udf(col(c)) else col(c) for c in date_df.columns)
)
```

I haven't tested this (pseudo)code (It would have helped if you have provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but I think something like this approach should work.

Answer (score 1):

To change the format of date columns, you can use date_format from pyspark sql functions. I created example data and tested,

```
 >>> for pyspark.sql import functions as F 
 >>> l=[('2018-01-22','id1',123,'2018-01-21'),('2018-01-22','id2',234,'2018-01-21'),('2018-01-22','id3',345,'2018-01-21'),('2018-01-22','id2',456,'2018-01-21')]
 >>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['date1','id','value','date2'])
 >>> df = df.select(df.date1.cast('date'),'id','value',df.date2.cast('date'))
 >>> df.printSchema()
 root
  |-- date1: date (nullable = true)
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- value: long (nullable = true)
  |-- date2: date (nullable = true)

 >>> df.show()
 +----------+---+-----+----------+
 |     date1| id|value|     date2|
 +----------+---+-----+----------+
 |2018-01-22|id1|  123|2018-01-21|
 |2018-01-22|id2|  234|2018-01-21|
 |2018-01-22|id3|  345|2018-01-21|
 |2018-01-22|id2|  456|2018-01-21|
 +----------+---+-----+----------+
 >>> dcols,cols = [],[]
 >>> for x in df.schema.fields:
 ...     if repr(x.dataType) == 'DateType':
 ...        dcols.append(x.name)
 ...     else:
 ...        cols.append(x.name)
 ...
 >>> dcols
 ['date1', 'date2']
 >>> cols
 ['id', 'value']
 >>> df.select([F.date_format(c,'MM/dd/yyy').alias('%s'%c) for c in dcols]+cols).show()
 +----------+----------+---+-----+
 |     date1|     date2| id|value|
 +----------+----------+---+-----+
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id1|  123|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id2|  234|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id3|  345|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id2|  456|
 +----------+----------+---+-----+

 ## If you still want to use UDF

 >>> from datetime import datetime
 >>> def conv(column):
 ...     date_format='%m/%d/%Y'
 ...     a = datetime.strptime(str(column),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime(date_format)
 ...     return a
 ...
 >>> conv_func = F.udf(conv)
 >>> df.select([conv_func(F.col(x)).alias('%s'%x) for x in dcols]+cols).show()
 +----------+----------+---+-----+
 |     date1|     date2| id|value|
 +----------+----------+---+-----+
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id1|  123|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id2|  234|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id3|  345|
 |01/22/2018|01/21/2018|id2|  456|
 +----------+----------+---+-----+
```

Hope this helps.